# How to parse an array inside EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I get a list of ID's from API, that needs to be added to a URL inside an EJS template, so I can fetch the correct items.

Example URL:
http://url.com/get/:id

Example ID's:
526
876
929

needed result inside EJS template:

```
<li> http://url.com/get/526 </li>
<li> http://url.com/get/876 </li>
<li> http://url.com/get/929 </li>
```

I got the list of ID's as needed, but I can't figure out why my forEach loop won't return the URL+ID.

This is console.log of message:

```
[ 526, 876, 929 ]
```

This is the EJS file:

```
<% var itemurl = "http://url.com/get/" %>

<% message.forEach(itemView) => { %>
    <%= item url + itemView %>
<% }); %>
```

I keep getting syntax errors and obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: "syntax errors" — What, precisely, do the error messages say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% var message  = [112,232,533] %>
<% var itemurl = "http://url.com/get/" %>

<% message.forEach((itemView) => { %>
    <%= itemurl + itemView %>
<% }); %>
```

you were missing an open parenthesis and had a space in itemurl